Is there a way to read a static table when using polars for a sqlite catalog with PyIceberg
I am doing a PoC with polars PyIceberg, and following along with this tutorial by tabular.io.
I managed to get everything to work using a sqlite catalog. Now I am trying to see whether I can read a static table directly from the metadata.json. The tutorial says:
df = pl.scan_iceberg(
   "s3://bucket/path/to/iceberg-table/metadata.json", ...
)

However, my local warehouse looks like this
I managed to do this
def get_latest(path: Path, pattern: str = "*"):
    files = path.glob(pattern)
    return max(files, key=lambda x: x.stat().st_ctime).as_posix()


pl.scan_iceberg(get_latest(warehouse_path / "dis.db/zorgproducten/metadata", "*.metadata.json")).collect()

But I was wondering: isn't there a built-in method in PyIceberg (or in the Iceberg spec) to do this proper? This feels a bit hacky. Or is this not supported with sqlite catalog?

That error seems to be because you're passing a Pathlib object? What happens if you stringify it? str(warehouse_path / "dis.db/ref-diagnoses/metadata/")

Ah, of course. At least this get me a bit further @jqurious pl.scan_iceberg(     str(warehouse_path / "dis.db/zorgproducten/metadata/00001-4dfa5e6d-1e29-45bd-97af-c9c9842cec54.metadata.json") ).collect()

But then I still have the challenge that I need to manually lookup which *-metadata.json is the most recent one. Isn't there a built-in method for that, I wonder?

I've no idea about the iceberg side of things - sorry. But perhaps this allows you to edit your question to match up with the real goal.

Just edited the original question.
